# PHP insists on a wrong timezone

Tags: php, apache, dst

Here is a script with the output of each line in a comment next to each statement to demonstrate my problem

```
<?php
    echo date_default_timezone_get(); //Europe/Helsinki
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo');
    $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
        echo "\nScript timezone differs from ini-set timezone."; //True, this block is ran
    } else {
        echo "\nScript timezone and ini-set timezone match.";
    }
    echo "\n".date_default_timezone_get(); //Africa/Cairo
    echo "\n'".ini_get('date.timezone')."'"; //''
    echo "\n".date('Z'); //10800
    echo "\n".date("m/d/Y h:i:s A T",strtotime("-1 hour")); //I still have to do this to obtain the correct date !
?>
```

I'm in Cairo where we no longer have DST for around 3 years now. The server's timezone is set correctly and DST option isn't even available to enable or disable DST. So it is inherently disabled. Here is a screenshot to demonstrate

[image]

In my `php.ini` file

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
;date.timezone =
```

My **php** version is

```
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2011 17:28:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

- Even after I set my default timezone, why do still have to manipulate the `date()` output (i.e. reducing it by one hour) to get the correct time which matches the server time ?
- And why does it insist that `Europe/Helsinki` is my timezone ?
- Could this have anything to do with Apache ?

Comment: why not set the timezone in php.ini?

Comment: Is the server the same Windows machine you show screenshots from?

Comment: @Jon, yes. I'm even using Win7 and the look and feel is different so I didn't mix up

Comment: so your suggesting php routines has not been updated to reflect your DST regulations?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: For the DST issue, PHP comes with an internally bundled timezone database which is obviously out of date -- what version of PHP are you on? For the default timezone, if you are on PHP < 5.4 the environment variable `TZ` overrides this setting.

Comment: @DevZer0, I'm sorry I do no understand what do you mean. I'm not a php pro btw :)

Comment: @Jon, my php version is 5.2.17. Full version info is updated in the question now.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana i suggest you try updating your php, your version is bit ancient. Your missing out on many improvements.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana: The easiest way by far to fix your problems is to upgrade to a more recent PHP version. Note that PHP 5.2 has been end-of-lifed for more than three years now, so there is more than enough reason to do it. Upgrading to the most recent 5.4 or 5.5 will fix everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DST information is stored in timezonedb, a database that comes with every PHP installation by default. Since your PHP version is positively ancient and you're saying the DST setting for your country has recently changed, the timezonedb is simply out of date. It needs to be kept updated either by updating PHP itself or by updating the database through PECL.

See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php, http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb, [How to install PECL extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php).

Comment: Can you confirm that further PHP updates are `fully` backward compatible ?

Comment: Between PHP 5.2 and the current 5.5 there may or may not have been some breaking changes. I can't tell you for sure that your scripts will work as is, you need to test that yourself. You should do so anyway and prepare to move on, since 5.2 is no longer supported.

Comment: I'll go ahead with that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is it ok to install a 32-bit php version on a 64-bit system ? I see that 64-bit php versions are still experimental.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an 'e' on your date function.

> Timezone  --- ---
>   e   Timezone identifier (added in PHP 5.1.0)    Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores

Or you can use an 'I' for DST

Source;
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope this solved your problem :)